# Trying to keep contents of checkbox List when returned to page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a checkbox list and a button on page 1, a label and a button on page 2. What I'm trying to do is remember what checkboxes were checked, when returning to page1 from page 2.any ideas? I'm lost here's my code. I tried making a collection but that didn't work? Or should a array be used??

Page1.aspx

```
 namespace Form
 {
 public partial class Page2 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string daysrequested = "";
        int count = 0;

        foreach (ListItem daysItem in Checkboxlist1.Items)
        {
            if (daysItem.Selected)
            {

                daysrequested += "  <br /> " + daysItem.Value;
                count++;

            }
        }

        Session["daysre"] = daysrequested;
        Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
    }
```

Page2.aspx

```
  using System;
  using System.Collections.Generic;
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Web;
  using System.Web.UI;
  using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

  namespace Form
 {
  public partial class Page21 : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string days = (string)Session["daysre"];
        daysLabel.Text = String.Format("You picked" + days);
    }

    protected void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Response.Redirect ( "Page1.aspx");
    }
    }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not use a `string` as the data type to hold the check box list items' value, but rather a `List<string>`, since `ListItem`'s `Value` property is a `string`, like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> daysrequested = new List<string>();

    foreach (ListItem daysItem in Checkboxlist1.Items)
    {
        if (daysItem.Selected)
        {
            daysrequested.Add(daysItem.Value);
        }
    }

    Session["daysre"] = daysrequested;
    Response.Redirect("Page2.aspx");
}
```

Now in the `Page_Load` of page 2, you can pull the list out of `Session`, like this:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> requestedDays = new List<string>();
    requestedDays = Session["daysre"] as List<string>;

    StringBuilder theRequestedDaysStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(string day in requestedDays)
    {
        theRequestedDaysStringBuilder.Append(day);
    }

    daysLabel.Text = String.Format("You picked" + theRequestedDaysStringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Finally, to recheck the check boxes in page 1, do this in the `Page_Load`:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // Check to see if daysre is in session cache
    if(Session["daysre"] != null)
    {
        // Get list from session cache
        List<string> requestedDays = new List<string>();
        requestedDays = Session["daysre"] as List<string>;

        // Loop through each value in list
        foreach(string day in requestedDays)
        {
            theRequestedDaysStringBuilder.Append(day);

            // Loop through each item in check box list
            foreach (ListItem daysItem in Checkboxlist1.Items)
            {
                // Check to see if this item needs to be checked by 
                // comparing its value with current value in list
                if(daysItem.Value == day)
                {
                    // We have a match
                    // Make item checked and break out of loop
                    daysItem.Checked = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    StringBuilder theRequestedDaysStringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    foreach(string day in requestedDays)
    {
        theRequestedDaysStringBuilder.Append(day);
    }

    daysLabel.Text = String.Format("You picked" + theRequestedDaysStringBuilder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: OK this works, but how do I have the checkboxes rechecked when I return to page 1 in the pageload

Answer (score 0):

On Page 1 :

On Button Click store the checked values of Check List in a session 
and also assign one more session("Page2Visited")="1"

in page_load function

if session("Page2Visited") = "1"  then

assign all stored session values as checked to check list

else

keep all values in checklist as unchecked

end if

clear all sessions

Answer (score 0):

First of all, it's not pretty well idea to keep your selected items inside a string variable and later store in Session object. You can add them into an array or generic list. Later, you can format your display string (inside page_load method of Page2 page) reading your array items.

If you back to page1, your items won't be selected because you haven't handle it. You will need to read your previously setup Session object and select chosen items (inside Page1 Page_Load method) .

Answer (score 0):

I just made a solution to reproduce the error, copied pasted your whole code but didnt get any error, in fact its working exactly as u want

So maybe check once the page number 
Cause the code you provided says

```
public partial class Page21 : System.Web.UI.Page
```

On your Page2

Comment: Also please check if your
(ListItem daysItem in Checkboxlist1.Items)
Is correct